# How to get connection details on an authenticated port of an Extreme X450-G2 switch?

Tags: port, switch

I have an Extreme X450-G2 switch which has 48 ports. On one port (port 22) I have an active link (LEDs blink, webinterface shows that the port is active), yet I cannot seem to find out what is connected to said port.

Authentication on this port is set to Authentication required (active/discard) with both MAC as well as 802.1x enabled. No information can be found for the device which is connected to this port.

Normally, on an authenticated port I should see a lot of information about the connected device (MAC and IP address to say the least), but for this port, I cannot seem to find any information.

What command(s) can I use to find out which MAC and/or IP is connected to this port in order to find out what device is connected to the switch? Additionaly, what commands can I issue on the switch to get more information on the device?

Thanks!

Update 1: I forgot to mention that unplugging the devices is not an option. Most (if not all) of the devices that are unknown, are devices like sensors and building management hardware. Undocumented legacy stuff that has been around for a long time, but which can be critical none the less. Which makes it of course all the more necessary to know what these devices are doing on the network...
Following cables is also not an option, as most of these devices are tucked away in spaces and locations to which we do not have access to.

Comment: Maybe you can unplug the cable and then check what device loose connectivity.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Good call, and I would certainly try it in other situations, but in this case I do not know what devices are connected (so I could potentially unplug some critical device), and I have no idea where the devices are located (there are a few thousand devices in the building). Should have mentioned that in my question, so I've updated it to include the info - but thanks for your advice!

Comment: Another idea is to mirror the port to other port and attach laptop, sniff and record the traffic. This may help you to reveal MAC, IP, in some cases even the function of the device